# Using pandas.Dataframe.groupby without alphabetical ordering

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, alphabetical-sort

I have a dataframe that I want to alter (according to the code right below) but it put's all the 'Experiment' name values in alphabetical order. Is there a way to leave the order as it is after calling **pandas.Dataframe.groupby**?

```
df = df.groupby(['Experiment', 'Step'], as_index=False)['value'].aggregate(np.sum)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`groupby` takes a keyword argument `sort`, which by default is `True`. You should do:

```
df = df.groupby(['Experiment', 'Step'], sort=False, as_index=False)['value'].aggregate(np.sum)
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass the sort list? I mean, I'd like to tell pandas what is the sort rule.